# How to return SQLPLUS Null as \N

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I have a script that moves that from one DB to another by a SQL.
I'm querying from one side and load it into another. TSV style.
I'm expanding that script now to support Oracle as a source.
For that to work I need two things:

1. make the result return as tab.
2. return null as `\N`

`mysql` does both as default. `psql` has a flags for then `-AF $'\t' -P 'null=\N'`.

For (1) in `sqlplus` I can add before the SQLs `set colsep`. But for (2)
I have no idea how to do it. It can't be modification to SQL itself, either something to add before the SQL, `sqlplus` flag, or post command (maybe `sed`) that will happen when the data returns to the client (this is the least preferred option as there might be bugs in it).

Would love some help.

What I could find is

```
SQL> set null "\N"
SQL> select null from dual;

N
-
\
N


SQL> set null '\\N'
SQL> select null from dual;

N
-
\
\
N
```

But as you can see it doesn't like that backslash

Answer (score 0):

It is just about column width.

By default:

```
SQL> select null from dual;

N
-
```

Then you did this:

```
SQL> set null "\N"
```

and got this:

```
SQL> select null from dual;

N
-
\
N
```

If you *fix* column size ("NULL" is a string, 4 characters in length)    :

```
SQL> col null format a4
```

you get what you wanted:

```
SQL> select null from dual;

NULL
----
\N

SQL>
```

Comment: Fixing the column size using format isn't necessary. Simply ensuring that the select returns columns that are defined as longer than char(1) (i.e. `select cast ( null as varchar2 ( 10 ) ) as x from dual;` ) also works fine.

Comment: Likewise, @gsiems, *casting isn't necessary - simply fix column size* (i.e. both ways will do; as usual, one problem may have one, two or more solutions). Thank you for your comment!

Comment: Unfortunately both aren't ideal. I have no idea what the column name is/will be, and I can't manipulate the SQL. As the SQL is an argument in the script. I can only add code before the SQL, or to `sqlplus`.